# Calling a php function using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a php function in another file.
I want to call that function using JavaScript or jquery in order to run its output.

My php function:

```
public function viewAll()
{
    $query = " SELECT * FROM category";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) >= 1) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<option>" . $row['category_name'] . "</option>";
        }
    } else echo "category not found";
    if (isset($_POST['callFunc1'])) {
        echo func1($_POST['callFunc1']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which solutions have you found so far and with which are you having problems?

Comment: I have tried every solution and sample code existing on the internet. All the solutions were with parameters. I need a solution without sending parameters. I just want it to be called, not anything else.

Comment: Even though I doubt you found every existing solution on the internet, please post some and explain why they don't work for you, so that we don't waste our and your time suggesting  something you already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call server side function from client side. You need to use ajax for this

Here is the code snippet.

```
<script>

function myCall() {
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        type: "GET",            
        dataType: "html"
    });

    request.done(function(msg) {
        $("#YourID").html(msg);         
    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: That sounds useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so add a file called `/mghaffari.php`. In that file, put this

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
viewAll();
exit;
```

Then to call it with jQuery

```
$.get("/mghaffari.php", function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Check your console for the output!

---

Check out the docs for [jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use AJAX for that.  PHP is all code found and run on the server, JavaScript code is all code that runs on the client of the person viewing the page.  An AJAX call will send a request back the server so it can call some PHP function for you and give you the result.

Comment: I don't know anything about Ajax, jQuery or JavaScript. Give me some sample codes, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery.Ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) which basicaly lets you call Files (doesnt matter if txt,php,ect.) and returns its content. If its a php file you get the parsed answer, of course.

Comment: Thanks. But as as I said to Lochemage, I strongly need sample codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX to retrieve your function response:

```
$('body').load( 'url/viewAll.php' ); // Load viewAll.php
```

In the PHP controller you call to the function:

```
viewAll();
```

Now, `body` is replaced by the `viewAll` response. See about load: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

Although perhaps not ideal for your particular situation (the above suggestions would work fine for such a simple request). To answer the question of is it possible, you *can* call server side code from the client side using something like this (although it is not directly calling the function):

[JSON-RPC (php <=> javascript)](https://github.com/jcubic/json-rpc).

I have not used this package myself but have implemented something similar using php's reflection capabilities that are then exposed to the client via a Javascript output file. Communication is via JSON and allows you to access PHP classes/methods from the client.